# After migration of java from 11 to 17 and Spring to 3.0 Spring Cloud Config doesn't work correctly for provideing properties for the services

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-boot-3

We have a Spring Cloud Config, that is set up  via `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8070

management: #https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info,health,monitoring,refresh,env,mappings
  security:
    enabled: "false"
  server:
    port: 18070

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          sql: SELECT key,value FROM config.properties WHERE application=? AND profile=? AND label=?
          order: 0
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://@db.host@:5432/config_db
    username: name
    password: @db.name.pwd@
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 5000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      minimum-idle: 1
      idle-timeout: 10000
      data-source-properties: ApplicationName=config-server
  profiles:
    active: jdbc
```

When the properties are requested,

```
GET /{application}/{profile}/{label}
```

we get `405` Http answer instead of `200` and value of the property we want to request.

Why changes with

```
Dockerfile

build_artifacts:
  extends: .gradle.build
  -image: ${NEXUS_DEV_REGISTRY}/docker-remote/gradle:6.9.4-jdk11-focal
  +image: ${NEXUS_DEV_REGISTRY}/docker-remote/gradle:7.5.0-jdk17-jammy

build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext {
        -springBootVersion = '2.1.8.RELEASE'
        +springBootVersion = '3.1.0'
    }
```

Spring Cloud versions:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:4.0.2'
implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server:${springBootVersion}"
```

Comment: is there an error in the logs on the config server side? What version of spring cloud as 3.1.0 is only for boot.

Comment: @spencergibb we had that:

Comment: implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:4.0.2'
implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server:${springBootVersion}"

Comment: It should be the same version as starter config, not boot version